# How is graphite versioned?

Tags: graphite

[0.9.12](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphite-web) available at pypi

[launchpad](https://launchpad.net/graphite/+series) jumps to 0.10 after 0.9.10 with no mention of .11 or .12

[github](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web) indicates 0.9.11

the [official documentation](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.12/) does talk about but doesn't provide links for download for 0.9.12.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a programming question..

Comment: Isn't versioning a crucial part of it?

Comment: Yeah but this is a Q&A for *specific programming problems*. As in issues of programming, logic or typical questions. I think a dodgy versioning method doesn't come under that scope.

Comment: i, in the capacity of a _programmer_ want to ask the fellow _programmers_ about a very specific programming question- "where to begin development so as to avoid building up on bugs and/or resolving already solved ones?". This isn't _the-best-place_, but we can't have an altogether different forum for miscellaneous issues regarding the programming environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphite uses [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/).

0.9.x is the "Current Stable Release" branch and 0.10.x is the "Active Development" branch (as indicated by the launchpad page). If you're looking for the most pain-free version you should work with the latest version on the stable release branch, currently 0.9.12, available from [github](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/releases/tag/0.9.12) and [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphite-web).